# siunitx redefines macros in pdf bookmarks

Tags: pdf, siunitx, bookmarks

I want to use the macro `\as` for abbreviations in my document. However, `siunitx` interferes with its use in pdf bookmarks. The following MWE produces a document with a section named "foo" in the document, but "as" in the pdf bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\def\as{foo}
\section{\as}

\end{document}
```

This seems to be due to the fact that `siunitx` defines `\as` as a unit shorthand (attosecond) and seems to want to help me use it in pdf bookmarks. However, it fails to detect that I am not using `\as` inside a unit macro.

- Is this a bug or just an unfortunate feature?
- Is there a workaround to avoid this behavior? I did not find anything about removing units in the `siunitx` documentation.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\AtBeginDocument
{\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\as{foo}}}
\begin{document}

\def\as{foo}
\section{\as}

\end{document}
```

[image]